# DrawingManager on StreetView? Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to use the DrawingManager library to draw polylines and polygons on a Google StreetView overlay?

I would like to implement some house height and roof angle measuring functions via user-drawn polyline(s), but even if I instantiate and enable the DrawingManager on a StreetView overlay, all mouse and keyboard events simply control the StreetView navigation instead of actually drawing polylines and polygons.

It seems that the DrawingManager library will not work on a StreetView overlay.  Is this correct?  Or do I need to disable a bunch of StreetView options like panning and zooming controls for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I am almost sure that you can't draw it over google maps, even disabling all the options you stated.